# Автоподсказка при вводе

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения, javascript

Хочу сделать подсказку при вводе почты, написал такое регулярное выражение, но оно работает только когда почта уже полностью введена, как сделать что бы выражение подходило когда введено даже ещё не все, но только после того как юзерр уже ввел "@"

Например "mail@y" или "mail[@yandex](/users/3378/yandextnu)."

```
/[-\w.]+@yandex\.ru/.exec('mail@yandex.ru');
```

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/P7a5h/1/). Только добавьте все необходимые проверки. Например, проверка на один символ "@", да и вообще, валидность мыла.

Answer (score 1):

Так для любых доменов:

```
/[-\w.]+@[-\w]+(?:\.\w{2,4})?/.exec('mail@yandex.ru');
```

Так только для яндекса:

```
/[-\w.]+@y(?:a(?:n(?:d(?:e(?:x(?:\.(?:ru?)?)?)?)?)?)?)/.exec('mail@yandex.ru');
```